# LaTeX: update '\leftmark' automatically on '\chapter*{abc123}'

Tags: latex

In my current document there are some chapters that have to be added with the `\chapter*`-command because I don't want them to be *real chapters* (no entry in toc, no chapter-number, ...). This works fine.

But in my header I want the `chapter-name` to be displayed. I'm using `fancyheaders` and `\leftmark`:

```
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\leftmark}
```

The problem is, that for chapters added with the `\chapter*`-command, `\leftmark` is not updated and so the header still displays the chapter-name of the previous chapter.

Therefore I either need to force `\chapter*` to automatically update `\leftmark`, or I switch to the `\chapter`-command but prevent the other stuff that comes along (entry in toc, ...). but I don't know how! Any ideas?

Comment: You might want to post this on http://tex.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Answer (score 7):

The * forms of the `\chapter` etc. commands do not call the mark commands. So if you want your preface to set the header info but not be numbered nor be put in the table of contents, you must issue the `\markboth` command yourself, e.g.

```
\chapter*{abc123\markboth{abc123}{}}
```

Answer (score 3):

I just had redefined chapter and section command to what I need and had set the `\leftmark` explicitly. Chapter commands will not able to use leftmark anymore, but I don't care as I'm using my `\nnchapter` and `\nnsection` commands in the whole document

```
\newcommand{\nnchapter}[1]{
   \phantomsection
   \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}\renewcommand{\leftmark}{#1}\chapter*{#1}
}
\newcommand{\nnsection}[1]{
   \phantomsection
   \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}\renewcommand{\leftmark}{#1}\section*{#1}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 \let\oldleftmark=\leftmark
    \chapter*{My New Leftmark}
    \renewcommand{\leftmark}{My New Leftmark}
      ...
      Your text
      ...
    \pagebreak
    \chapter{Next Chapter}
    \let\leftmark=\oldleftmark
```

`pagebreak` is required to ensure the new `lefmark` is used

Answer (score 1):

allright, i did it! the solution is to redefine \leftmark only within a specific block! pretty simple if you know it ;)

```
{
    \renewcommand{\leftmark}{ABC123}
    \chapter*{ABC123}

    %... and so on ...
}
```

Comment: Do I understand correctly: you are redefining \leftmark for every \chapter* ??

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this will work, because I don't have LaTeX installed on my current machine...

But you could try setting a \markleft command after your \chapter* command like so:

```
\chapter*{Chapter title goes here}
\markleft{Chapter title goes here}  % content should be added to the \leftmark
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your answer! but the problem is, that if i once set \leftmark manually, later \chapter-commands won't update it again!

Comment: Seems that is intended. See [fancy header documentation][1] pages 10-11 for further detail on the matter.

 [1]:http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.pdf